# Solr with Tomcat delta import doesn't work

Tags: tomcat, solr, lucene, dataimporthandler, delta-index

I'm new to Solr.
I want to ask a question, I don't know why does my solr delta-import doesn't work. I think that I have configured my core solr config, schema, and data-config properly.

Full-import works well but delta-import doesn't.

I guess that my Solr doesn't read "last_index_time properly" on dataimport.properties because in my dataimport.properties file there's no "dataimport.last_index_time".

This is my solr core configuration:

**solrconfig.xml**

```
<!-- DIH -->

    <!--<lib dir="../../../contrib/dataimporthandler/lib/" regex=".*\.jar" />-->
    <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-\d.*\.jar" />

    <requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
        <lst name="defaults">
              <str name="config">db-data-config.xml</str>
          </lst>
    </requestHandler>
<!-- -->
```

**schema.xml**

```
<!-- DIH -->
   <!--<dynamicField name="*_name"  type="text_general"   multiValued="false" indexed="true"  stored="true" />-->
   <!--<dynamicField name="c_*"  type="text_general"   multiValued="false" indexed="true"  stored="true" />-->
   <field name="judul" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
   <field name="isi" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
   <field name="tgl_publikasi" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
   <field name="id_sort" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />

   <copyField source="id" dest="id_sort" />
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
```

**db-data-config.xml**

```
<dataConfig>
  <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"
            driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/medmon_skripsi"
            user="root"
            password="" /> 
  <document>

    <entity name="berita" pk="id" query="select id, c_title, c_isi, c_pubdate from t_berita" deltaImportQuery="select id, c_title, c_isi, c_pubdate from t_berita where id='$(dih.delta.id)'" deltaQuery="select id from t_berita where c_last_modified &gt; '$(dih.last_index_time)'">
        <field name="judul" column="c_title" />
        <field name="isi" column="c_isi" />
        <field name="tgl_publikasi" column="c_pubdate" /> 
    </entity>

  </document>
</dataConfig>
```

**dataimport.properties**

```
#Sun May 03 14:47:26 ICT 2015
last_index_time=2015-05-03 14\:47\:06
berita.last_index_time=2015-05-03 14\:47\:06
```

I try to see delta-import work by add one record to MySQL RDBMS, but I didn't see my delta-import work. (index not updated)

FYI I used **Solr 4.10.3** with **Tomcat 8.0.20**

Comment: please check the below links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21580331/solr-delta-import-not-working     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20167950/delta-import-collects-the-data-but-dont-update-the-solr-index

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18660294/solr-delta-import-does-not-work                                                                     <propertyWriter dateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" type="SimplePropertiesWriter" directory="data" filename="my_dih.properties" locale="en_US" /> is missing.. read about Configuring The Property Writer https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Delta-Import_Example

Comment: still does'nt work.
from the link above, I've tried using "localhost:8080/solr/collection1/dataimport?command=delta-import&commit=true" and add **<propertyWriter dateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" type="SimplePropertiesWriter" directory="conf" filename="dataimport.properties" locale="en_US" />** in my db-data-config.xml .

btw thanks for the answer @AbhijitBashetti :) 
maybe any other idea ?  :/

Comment: anybody know what is the problem ?